# The subsets $\{(x, y)\in\Bbb R^2|(y^2−x)(y^2−x−1) = 0\}$ and $\{(x, y)\in\Bbb R^2|y^2−x^2=1\}$ of $\Bbb R^2$ (with induced metric) are homeomorphic.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The subsets $\{(x, y)\in\Bbb R^
2
| (y^
2 − x)(y^
2 − x − 1) = 0\}$ and $\{(x, y)\in\Bbb R^
2
|y^
2 − x^
2 = 1\}$
of $\Bbb R^
2$
(with the induced metric) are homeomorphic?

I think that the answer should be false.Although both sets are not path connected but
the first set according to me must be a connected set and the second set is clearly disconnected . Therefore they cannot be homeomorphic to each other. Is this correct or if not then kindly guide me .

Comment: The first set is not connected either, it is the union of two parabolas which have empty intersection

Comment: can you edit the question using LaTeX?

Comment: Can someone explain why is the first set not connected ? As we approach towards positive infinity the two graphs cannot be separated as the distance between them approaches zero. How can we then find a separation, and by separation I mean 2 open disjoint sets containing the two parts of the graph. @SoumikMukherjee

Comment: I am comparing the first set with the standard example of the Topologist's sine curve which is also a connected set by a similar logic I suppose.

Comment: Consider the open sets $\{(x,y)|y^2<x+1/2\}$ and $\{(x,y)|y^2>x+1/2\}$.

Comment: Yeah okay. I got it. Thank you very much. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm glad to help

Answer (score 1):

The subset $x^2-y^2=1$ is the union of two curves $y=\sqrt{1+x^2}$ and $y=-\sqrt{1+x^2}$. Consider the respective projection maps on the pair of straight lines $y=\pm1$.

Similarly the subset $(y^2-x-1)(y^2-x)=0$  is the union of two parabolas $y^2=x+1$ and $y^2=x$. Consider the respective projection maps on the pair of lines $x=-1$ and $x=0$.

As each subset is homeomorphic to a pair of parallel lines, they are homeomorphic to each other.

Comment: $x^2-y^2 = 1$ is not an equation of a parabola but of a hyperbola

Comment: @Jakobian Thanks, corrected.

Comment: Instead of projection, why not just say that graph of a function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$? Both sets are a disjoint union of two such graphs, so homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\sqcup \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Jakobian I thought projection would be better to visualize the homeomorphism

Comment: I kind of get your explanation. Although I think  I have misunderstood something in topology then. Please see my comment above and clarify my doubt. @SoumikMukherjee